Errors when doing any npm command in vs code
when i run ANY npm commands i just get this, it dosent matter what folder or project im on and it all started from when i tried installing the react-draggable. i have been having loads of errors and no amount of restarting, reinstalling seems to be helping so idk what else to do. i also have added the system 32 into my environments in windows advanced profile setting but still nothing. here are 2 errors i have been getting:
this one when trying to start a react app, it was working fine before trying to add the draggable thing as stated but now i get this:
PS C:\Users\lewis\react> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\lewis\react\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\lewis\react\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-14T20_47_31_482Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\lewis\react> 

aswell as this one when using the >create react app in vscode:
Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:284:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:477:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

this one is when trying to create a new react app using the terminal instead of the extention:
C:\Users\lewis\REACT PLZ WORK>npm install -g create-react-app
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 66 packages in 8s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

C:\Users\lewis\REACT PLZ WORK>
C:\Users\lewis\REACT PLZ WORK>npm fund
REACT PLZ WORK


C:\Users\lewis\REACT PLZ WORK>

I have a feeling these are linked somehow but i have no idea how to fix it and i have been trying for days.
thanks for anyone who helps!!
i have tried reinstalling node.js but get this error when powershell open, i get it even after letting it install chocolatey itself (deleting it fully and letting the installer do it) and tried updating it manually but its already at the latest version.
ARNING: 'choco' was found at 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe'.
WARNING: An existing Chocolatey installation was detected. Installation will not continue. This script will not
overwrite existing installations.
If there is no Chocolatey installation at 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey', delete the folder and attempt the installation
again.

Please use choco upgrade chocolatey to handle upgrades of Chocolatey itself.
If the existing installation is not functional or a prior installation did not complete, follow these steps:
 - Backup the files at the path listed above so you can restore your previous installation if needed.
 - Remove the existing installation manually.
 - Rerun this installation script.
 - Reinstall any packages previously installed, if needed (refer to the lib folder in the backup).

Once installation is completed, the backup folder is no longer needed and can be deleted.
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Upgrading the following packages:
python;visualstudio2019-workload-vctools
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
python v3.12.3 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
visualstudio2019-workload-vctools v1.0.1 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

Chocolatey upgraded 0/2 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
Type ENTER to exit:

got it on the first time i set node.js up to.

fixed it, i had to run a self-scan in the command prompt and i found 2 corrupt files that, now repaired, everything works :)

fixed it, i had to run a self-scan in the command prompt and i found 2 corrupt files that, now repaired, everything works :)
